# Deployment group automation:How to create an object query to add objects in label into deployment group

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to automate the deployment process of informatica objects from Dev to QA server.
Steps followed:

1. Create label : pmrep
2. Apply label: pmrep
   using a txt file which contains the object details, such as, foldername,objecttype,objectname.
3. Create dynamic deploymentgroup:pmrep
   providing query as parameter
   in query used argument as label equals to label name (created earlier)

(or)

4. Addobject to deployment group:pmrep
   using persistent input file(created from Executequery).

If i provide object type as label in it, it's not supporting.
So, in both 3 and 4 step we need a query which is created manually from repository manager to add objects which are present on label.

Please help us automate the process(to add the objects in label to deployment group) via script or any alternate pmrep commands to resolve the issue, as there is no commands available for creation of object query.

Note: Information is based on Unix server, so i can use Unix scripts to access the metadata table.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not supporting"? Can you share some screens?

Answer (score 0):

you will not need objectnames as Dynamic deployment group objects will be added at runtime using the query execution.
Query will add whatever objects present in label.